# Ubuntu: How do I install ruby 1.8.7 specifically?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I can't use RVM, this is a server not just for me, so I can't have RVM attached only to my user. Is there a way to install RVM universally? or is there a command where I can specify the version of ruby I want?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ruby1.8.7 ruby1.8.7-dev`

Comment: -1 Read RVM's ["Installing RVM
Quick (guided) Install "](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) section, and pay attention to the term "Multi-User installations".

Answer (score 3):

The RVM [Installation Guide](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) covers a "Multi-User Install". It will walk you through installing RVM in `/usr/local/rvm`.

But... you may not need RVM...

If I recall correctly, Ubuntu's default Ruby is version 1.8.7.  You can look in the [Software Center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter) or use [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) for which Ruby version is available for install. If you want to see available Ruby packages from the command  line then use `sudo apt-cache search ruby`. Once you determine the Ruby version is 1.8.7 then you can install it using your method of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Usually only a very limited set of versions is available. You can see them with `apt-cache policy <package>`. If you see one you want, you can specify it with `apt-cache install <package>=<version>`.

More often, you would just build from source precisely the version you want. Downloading the `deb` file for a particular version and installing it with `dpkg` is also a possibility, but keep in mind that `dpkg` won't be able to download and install dependent packages.